# Can I develop web and desktop apps on Ubuntu using C#?

Tags: application-development, web-development, c#

I am new to Ubuntu (using 14.04) and Linux in general. Professionally I work on HTML,PHP, CSS, C# and C. I know I can use HTML, PHP, CSS and C but I am not sure about C#. In Windows there is Visual Studio which helps a lot with developing desktop apps, and web projects.

Can I use C# for development in Ubuntu/Linux, and if yes, then how?

I will appreciate links to related resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/).

> Sponsored by Microsoft, Mono is an open source implementation of
>   Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the
>   Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active
>   and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to
>   become the leading choice for development of cross platform
>   applications.